# "webelement object is not iterable" when trying to access dropdown menu with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

The below function is called after a user clicks to select a dropdown menu with Selenium. I want to create a tkinter window that displays all of the options of the dropdown menu, and to print the users selection.

I'm getting "webelement object is not iterable." When finding similar issues online, it's because they were doing "find element by" instead of "find elements by." The problem is I'm not finding an element by a predefined id, I'm manipulating the currently active element. Is there some way to get all of the options starting at the active element like I'm doing here?

In runtime, this element is selected by the user while the program is running, so using "find elements by" isn't an option unless the needed attributes can be extracted by manipulating the active element.

```
def SubmitInput(dropdown_selection):
    print(dropdown_selection)
    confirm_dropdown_input_window.destroy()

active_element = driver.switch_to.active_element
options = [x for x in active_element]
confirm_dropdown_input_window = Tk()
enter_correct_dropdown_prompt = Label(confirm_dropdown_input_window,
                                  text='Please select the correct value below.')
dropdown = OptionMenu(confirm_dropdown_input_window, options[0], options, command=SubmitInput)
enter_correct_dropdown_prompt.grid(row=0, column=0)
dropdown.grid(row=1, column=0)
confirm_dropdown_input_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: We'll need to see the relevant HTML or at least get a link to the page under test to diagnose this.

Comment: The page I was testing was: https://store.cardsagainsthumanity.com/

I add any item to cart and use the dropdown where you enter the state.

Comment: Your `driver.switch_to.active_element` returns a div that covers the whole page. I'm not sure what dropdown you are targeting, is it the one with countries?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.